# How to jq a nested json

Tags: json, jq

I would like to catch a value using jq for Storage and Container in my json in order to pass it as variable in bash but I have problem parsing it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "Containers": {
      "value": [
        {
          "Storage": "abdelvt33cpgsa",
          "RG": "samitestik2",
          "Container": "lama"
        },
        {
          "Storage": "abdelvt44cpgsa",
          "RG": "samitestik2",
          "Container": "baba"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result would be that x = abdelvt33cpgsa and y = lama

Comment: There are two entries in `value[]` why do you need only the first?

Comment: @Inian I will loop over them anyways for each loop i will use one of the values for storage and container in order to deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it!
Here is my answer.

```
.parameters.Containers.value[].Storage
.parameters.Containers.value[].Container
```